Does Rig Veda talk about a heliocentric model of the solar system?
https://www.indiatoday.in/india/madhya-pradesh/video/india-not-columbus-discovered-america-claims-madhya-pradesh-education-minister-inder-singh-parmar-2598056-2024-09-11
While addressing students at a program at Bhopal's Barkatullah University, Madhya Pradesh Education Minister Inder Singh Parmar said

The Rigveda, written 8,000 years ago, states that the moon revolves around its parent body, the Earth, and the Earth revolves around the sun.

Where exactly does Rig Veda say that?

This verse can be found in Brahmana layer:

The Sun causes day and night on the earth,
because of revolution,
when there is night here, it is day on the other side,
the sun does not really rise or sink.

—Aitareya Brahmana III.44 (Rigveda)
These are necessarily conclusions that can only be reached with a heliocentric model of the solar system.
See also:

The sun moves in its own orbit but holding earth and other heavenly bodies in a manner that they do not collide with each other through force of attraction.
-Rig Veda 1.35.9

However it appears other translations of the 2nd reference are also seen, so that may not be the most solid evidence.
However, I hope this still answers the question.
